# tikz: disperse images symmetrically in a bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, scoping

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1]
    \node(a) at (0.0, 0.0){\includegraphics[width=1.0\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node(a) at (a.east)[anchor=west]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth]{example-image-b}};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[at (scope1.south), anchor=north, local bounding box=scope2]
    \node(c) at (scope2.south west)[anchor=north west]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\paperwidth]{example-image-c}};
    \node(d) at (c.east)[anchor=west]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth]{example-image}};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

I would like to centre the images in scope 2 symmetrically?

[image]

What should I fix?

Comment: What do you mean with `centre symmetrically`? Is the second picture the desired output?

Comment: @Excelsior, yes like in the second picture.

Comment: Is there a defined distance between c and d? For me it looks quite random ...

Comment: @Excelsior, it looks random because I adjusted the picture in inkscape. Possibly in tikz there are much better ways to disperse the images in scope2?

Comment: Therefore I asked, if you want this specific output or better center a and c and b and d

Comment: @Excelsior, centre a and b; c and d.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123875/discussion-between-excelsior-and-viesturs).

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, the centering depends on the difference of the width of the pictures you want to include. In your example, this difference is `0.2\paperwidth`, so I used a fraction of this value as a shift parameter for the second row of pictures.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node(a) at (0,0) {\includegraphics [width=1.0\paperwidth] {example-image-a}};
        \node(b) at (a.east) [anchor=west] {\includegraphics [width=0.5\paperwidth] {example-image-b}};
        \node(c) at ($ (a.south west) + (0.05\paperwidth,0) $) [anchor=north west] {\includegraphics [width=0.8\paperwidth] {example-image-c}};
        \node(d) at ($ (c.east -| b.south) - (0.05\paperwidth,0) $) {\includegraphics [width=0.5\paperwidth] {example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also skipped your `scope` environment, so maybe someone has a better solution for your problem.